# How to change Android TV action button text color programmatically?

Tags: android-tv, leanback

```js
val adapter = SparseArrayObjectAdapter()
    adapter.set(ACTION_PLAY_VIDEO, Action(ACTION_PLAY_VIDEO.toLong(), resources.getString(R.string.play_asset)))
    row.actionsAdapter = adapter
```

Here is my code for actions in DetailPage of AndroidTV
But I have no idea how I can change button text color /button background color programmatically not in xmls ?

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same problme. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Give your adapter a presenter.

In Java:

```java
adapter.setPresenterSelector(new ClassPresenterSelector()
    .addClassPresenter(Action.class, new Presenter() {

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_button_layout, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
            Button button = viewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.my_button_id);
            //do stuff here, like
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            button.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            //or
            button.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, hasFocus) -> {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    //change color?
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnbindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            //required override
        }

    })
);
```